# how to remove decimal place in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-xi

i want to return a text or a number based on a field value in crystal report

```
local numberVar i;
i:=Roundup(({@a}/{@b})*100,0);
if{@a}=0 then ToText('N/A') else ToText(i);
```

the result is always this in crystal report

1. test_colum

   - N/A
   - N/a
   - 2.00
   - 3.00

since the integer value is converted to text using ToText() the integer results are appended with .00

Answer (score 7):

ToText (x, y) where y is a whole number indicating the number of decimal places to carry the value in x to.

[http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc%2Fhtml%2Ftopic629.html](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic629.html)